# Hive Script - How to transform table / find average of certain records according to one columns name?

Tags: hadoop, hive, transform, aggregate, average

I want to transform a Hive table by aggregating based on averages. However, I don't want the average value of an entire column, I want the average of the records in that column that have the same type in another column.

Here's an example, easier than trying to explain:

**TABLE I HAVE:**

Timestamp    CounterName    CounterValue    MaxCounterValue    MinCounterValue
00:00            Counter1            3                        3                            1
00:00            Counter2            4                        5                            2
00:00            Counter3            1                        4                            1

00:00            Counter4            6                        6                            1
00:05            Counter1            3                        5                            2
00:05            Counter2            2                        2                            2
00:05            Counter3            4                        5                            4
00:05            Counter4            6                        6                            5
.......

**TABLE I WANT:**
CounterName    AvgCounterValue    MaxCounterValue    MinCounterValue
Counter1            3                            5                                1
Counter2            3                            5                                2
Counter3            2.5                         5                                1
Counter4            6                            6                                1

So I have a list of a bunch of counters, which each have multiple records (one per 5 minute time period). Every time each counter is logged, it has a value, a max value during that 5 minutes, and a min value. I want to aggregate this huge table so that it just has one record for each counter, which records the overall average value for that counter from all the records in the table,and then the overall min/max value of the counter in the table.

The reason this is difficult is because all the documentation says is how to aggregate by the average of a column in one table - I don't know how to split it up in groups.

Here's the script I've started with:

```
FROM HighCounters INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE MdsHighCounters
SELECT 
    HighCounters.CounterName AS CounterName,
    HighCounters.CounterValue AS CounterValue
    HighCounters.MaxCounterValue AS MaxCounterValue,
    HighCounters.MinCounterValue AS MinCounterValue
GROUP BY HighCounters.CounterName;
```

And I don't know where to go from there... any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Note that Hive also has AVG, MAX and MIN functions for columns, so you could try to use them.

Comment: Nice. But you could add a complete answer for the future record.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own problem:

`FROM HighCounters INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE MdsHighCounters
SELECT 
    HighCounters.CounterName AS CounterName,
    AVG(HighCounters.CounterValue) AS CounterValue,
    MAX(HighCounters.MaxCounterValue) AS MaxCounterValue,
    MIN(HighCounters.MinCounterValue) AS MinCounterValue
GROUP BY HighCounters.CounterName;`

Does this look right to you?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was suggesting :)